# "Equality of Opportunity in Supervised Learning" implementation

Tags: machine-learning, algorithmic-fairness

I'm trying to find some fair/accountable/transparent (FAC) algorithms, and the ["Equality of Opportunity in Supervised Learning"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02413.pdf) seems pretty promissing. I was wondering if there's an implementation of the algorithms somewhere (I personally prefer python, but [almost] any language would do).

[1] Hardt, Moritz, Eric Price, and Nati Srebro. "Equality of opportunity in supervised learning." Advances in neural information processing systems. 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out people at IBM have implemented it in the AIF360 package ([github link](https://github.com/IBM/AIF360)).

The [resources](http://aif360.mybluemix.net/resources#overview) page lists the paper as one of the algorithms they've implemented.

It's implemented in [`aif360.algorithms.postprocessing.EqOddsPostprocessing`](https://aif360.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/postprocessing.html?highlight=eqoddspostprocessing#aif360.algorithms.postprocessing.EqOddsPostprocessing)

Answer (score 2):

The AIF360 package actually only implements the algorithm from section 4.1 in Hardt et al., i.e., the one that operates given a binary classification model. This will generally be suboptimal, and Hardt et al. also present (in section 4.2) an algorithm that takes a score predictor model as an input (i.e., a thing that predicts [0,1] and not {0,1}).

This latter algorithm is not implemented in AIF360, but [the fairlearn package has it implemented](https://fairlearn.org/main/user_guide/mitigation/postprocessing.html) (and a quite long and nice discussion of what it does and how it works).

Comment: @adrin noticing just now that you're a co-author of fairlearn, haha. Nice job!